# c++: undefined reference to vtable when using header but not without

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual

I have a interface and I want to create a `header` with the functions from the `interface` and a `.cpp` implementing the functions in this header. But when try this I always get the problem `undefined reference to 'vtable for Test'` in the `Testt.h` file.

I'm working on a rather big project in eclipse so I reduced my problem to a few small classes.

ITestAdapter.h:

```
#ifndef ITESTADAPTER_H_
#define ITESTADAPTER_H_

class TestAdapter {
public:
virtual int test() = 0;
};

#endif /* ITESTADAPTER_H_ */
```

Testt.h:

```
#ifndef TESTT_H_
#define TESTT_H_
#include "ITestAdapter.h"

class Test: public TestAdapter{
public:
virtual int test();
};

#endif /* TESTT_H_ */
```

Testt.cpp:

```
#include "Testt.h"
int test() {
return 0;
}
```

Test_main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Testt.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
Test t;
int i = t.test();
cout << i << endl;
return 0;
}
```

If I don't use the `Testt.h` at all and implement the interface within `Testt.cpp` and include `Testt.cpp` (what I want to avoid) within the file with my main-method then it works fine.

Testt.cpp (modified):

```
#include "ITestAdapter.h"
class Test: public TestAdapter {
public:
int test() {
    return 0;
}
};
```

So I don't understand why it doesn't work if I use a header (which I think would be the nicer solution).

I hope I could explain clearly what my problem is. If not please ask.

Comment: I have found this discussion, too. But somehow I just tried using destructors instead of the simple solution below.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining a non-member function `int test()` in `Testt.cpp`. You need to define `int Test::test()`:

```
int Test::test()
{// ^^^^
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Undefined reference to X means that the linker can't find the definition of X that has been declared.

You declared `Test` to have a member function `int test()` but this

```
int test() {
   return 0;
}
```

defines a free function.

You need

```
int Test::test() {
    return 0;
}
```

`undefined reference to 'vtable for Test'"` to test is a bit confusing. It usualy means that you [forgot to define the first virtual function of your class](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables).